# Any way to stop the "outside of your domain" notifications across Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

I use a GSuite account as my primary Google account for everything and across calendar / hangouts / etc, I see a "outside of your domain" notification for a lot of random things. Sometimes it's just a message - other times, I have to specifically allow someone from outside my domain to act.

Is there any global setting to allow it always across all apps?

Comment: Are you a regular user or the domain administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several G Suite apps have a setting for G Suite admins to enable/disable the warning, like Hangouts

From [Hangouts settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7486733?hl=en)

> **Hangouts out of domain warning**
>
> By enabling this setting, you provide a warning to users when they’re
>   having a Hangout with users of an external domain. As an
>   administrator, this also provides you with more visibility into how
>   users communicate with users outside your domain.

If you are a domain admin, go to https://admin.google.com then to each app settings page and change the corresponding setting accordingly

If you aren't a domain admin, ask your domain admin to change the domain warning settings.